# Opacity of element not set in media Query

Tags: css

Good Day

I am setting the `opacity` on 2 elements, an `li` element and an `image` element.
On a `hover` effect, I take away the opacities.

**Problem:** I am using a media query to display my site on mobile phones. Issue is that when I set the media query for `1024px`, I want to take away the `opacities` completely, but it does not trigger when the viewport is below 1024px ...refreshed as well

Why is that:

code:

HTML:

```
     <div id="app" class="span3">              
           <ul>
               <li id="apple"><a href="#" title="PartyAt for iPhone and iPad"><img src="images/apple.png" /></a></li>
               <li id="android"><a href="#"><img alt="PartyAt Android app on Google Play" src="images/android.png" /></a></li>                     
           </ul>
     </div>

 and

 <div id="social" class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span7"> 
            <div id="app2">              
                <a href="https://itunes.apple.com/za/app/partyat/id597807299?mt=8" title="PartyAt for iPhone and iPad"><img src="images/apple.png" /></a>
                <a href="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=io.ik.partyat"><img alt="PartyAt Android app on Google Play" src="images/android.png" /></a>        
            </div>              
        </div>      
        <div class="span5">
            <a href="" title="PartyAt SA facebook page" target="_blank"><img src="images/fb.png" border="0" /></a>
            <a href="" title="PartyAt SA twitter page" target="_blank"><img src="images/twitter.png" border="0" /></a>             
        </div>
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
#app ul li{
        opacity:0.7;
        -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=70)";
        filter:alpha(opacity=70);
        padding-bottom: 15px;
    }

 #social .span5 img {
        opacity: 0.7;
        -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=70)";
        filter:alpha(opacity=70);
    }
```

Media Query:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px;){
 #app ul li {
        opacity:1;
        -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
        filter:alpha(opacity=100);
        padding-bottom: 15px;
        }

 #social .span5 img {
        opacity: 1;
        -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
        filter:alpha(opacity=100);
 }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your media query is probably working, but after that, you are overwriting it:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px;){
    /* your custom styles... */
    #app ul li { opacity:1; }
}

/* normal styles */
#app ul li { opacity:0.7; }
```

So you can use `!important` to avoid conflict:

```
#app ul li { opacity:1 !important; }
```

**WARNING**: you should not use `!important` if there is a better solution. Please, read the following:

When two CSS rules are conflicting, the order of priority is:

1. rules with `!important` have top priority
2. inline styles are more important (e.g. `<div class="someclass" style="inline style"></div>` than normal styles
3. more specific rules > less specific (`#one .example tag .yeah` > `.yeah`)
4. if two rules have the same priority, the last one applied wins

So, inspect your CSS to see what's happening. Maybe you can just move your media query to the end of the stylesheet...

If you still have problems, please post a complete example.

Comment: I would argue against the use of !important. What would really benefit him is a thorough scan of the CSS in order to eliminate redundant properties.

Comment: Yeah, there is no need to use "!important" when the CSS is well coded. But as we don't have the complete CSS the easiest way to "solve" it is adding "important". I've added some info about rules priority so that he can find the problem. I'll add a warning so that he doesn't think "!important" is the best solution.

Comment: I actually did try the !important INSIDE the media query but it did not work.

Comment: Take a look at the order of the rule blocks in your CSS code. Also check if the media query works if you remove the normal CSS style. And as I said, you should post a more complete example (this way we can see the order and possible conflicting styles)

Comment: @  theBronx. Thank you for your answer. Maybe I'm too tired too see the obvious. Will keep on knocking the tree till something comes out.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have multiple calls of the same item. That's what happened to me. They were all stacked on top of each other and created a solid  item!

Comment: this is appropriate as comment rather than answer.